# How to authenticate to google OAuth2 in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, google-oauth

As a beginner to vue.js I'm struggling with this problem for days. 
I know that there are few plugins for that:

[vue-google-auth](https://github.com/simmatrix/vue-google-auth)

and

[vue-google-signin-button](https://github.com/phanan/vue-google-signin-button)

and

[vue-authenticate](https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate)

But none of these come with good documentations, so my attempts to make use of them failed. 
I also could not find any tutorial on vue.js with OAuth2 authentication after extensive googling. So appreciate if someone could come up with a full working example or refer me to some complete code.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you would be more specific on which area you are struggling with. Sample codes or whatever you have done would be helpful so that others could provide you with some good guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Example of usage without any plugins:

**index.html**

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="your-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com"
/>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-show="!profile" id="g-signin2"></div>
  <div v-if="profile">
    <pre>{{ profile }}</pre>
    <button @click="signOut">Sign Out</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.initGoogleAuth();
    this.renderGoogleAuthButton();
  },

  data() {
    return {
      profile: null
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onSignIn(user) {
      const profile = user.getBasicProfile();
      const fullName = profile.getName();
      const email = profile.getEmail();
      const imageUrl = profile.getImageUrl();
      this.profile = { fullName, email, imageUrl };
    },

    signOut() {
      var auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(() => {
        console.log("User signed out");
        this.profile = null;
      });
    },

    initGoogleAuth() {
      window.gapi.load("auth2", function () {
        window.gapi.auth2.init();
      });
    },

    renderGoogleAuthButton() {
      window.gapi.signin2.render("g-signin2", {
        onsuccess: this.onSignIn
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example with vue-google-oauth2.
You can install it with:

`npm i vue-google-oauth2`

Then you need to place these 2 lines of code in your APP ENTRY file, e.g. src/main.js

```
import GAuth from 'vue-google-oauth2'
Vue.use(GAuth, {clientId: 'XXXXXXXX'})
```

Where XXXXXXXX is the clientId you get from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/
I will assume you have been there if you've tried to login with Google before.

Then you create this component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <button @click="handleClickGetAuth" :disabled="!isInit">get auth code</button>
    <button @click="handleClickSignIn" v-if="!isSignIn" :disabled="!isInit">signIn</button>
    <button @click="handleClickSignOut" v-if="isSignIn" :disabled="!isInit">signOout</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'test',
  data () {
    return {
      isInit: false,
      isSignIn: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async handleClickGetAuth() {
      try {
        const authCode = await this.$gAuth.getAuthCode()
        const response = await this.$http.post('http://your-backend-server.com/auth/google', { code: authCode, redirect_uri: 'postmessage' })
      } catch (error) {
        // On fail do something
      }
    },

    async handleClickSignIn(){
      try {
        const googleUser = await this.$gAuth.signIn()
        console.log('user', googleUser)
        this.isSignIn = this.$gAuth.isAuthorized
      } catch (error) {
        // On fail do something
        console.error(error);
        return null;
      }
    },

    async handleClickSignOut(){
      try {
        await this.$gAuth.signOut()
        this.isSignIn = this.$gAuth.isAuthorized
      } catch (error) {
        // On fail do something
      }
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    let that = this
    let checkGauthLoad = setInterval(function(){
      that.isInit = that.$gAuth.isInit
      that.isSignIn = that.$gAuth.isAuthorized
      if(that.isInit) clearInterval(checkGauthLoad)
    }, 1000);
  }
  
}
</script>
```

All credits goes to

https://github.com/guruahn/vue-google-oauth2/blob/master/sample.html

Comment: The npm package `vue-google-oauth2` is DEPRECATED and no longer actively maintained.